# Can lands that say “Add one mana of any color to your mana pool” be used in a colorless EDH deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A couple of other questions have been asked regarding cards that "Add one mana of any color to your mana pool", but

1. [One is for EDH decks in general](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/can-i-use-a-card-with-add-one-mana-of-any-color-to-your-mana-pool-in-any-elder) (which, in most cases, have at least one color)
2. [The other is for colorless mana in general](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/can-colorless-mana-be-generated-from-things-that-say-add-one-mana-of-any-color) (which would likely also be used in a colored deck, or a non-EDH deck where extra colors don't matter)

What I'm trying to answer now is if those sorts of cards can be used in a colorless EDH deck.

So, for example, if I have one of the big Eldrazi as my commander, I know I can have [Coalition Relic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209158) in the deck because it has a colorless color identity. But, once it's on the field, can I use it to generate usable mana?

Comment: @Stephen - that's the question he linked to.  This question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Stephen, Neither of the two questions I linked to clearly answered my question. I'm asking about, specifically, _colorless_ EDH decks and trying to figure out what are legal ways to generate mana for them. The two other questions deal with "Any color mana" for EDH, and with regards to colorless-ness, but neither deal with it directly. Since colorless EDH decks are a rather strange beast and has generated a lot of questions and discussion in my play group, I felt a specific question was warranted.

Comment: @cdeszaq In all cases the answer is "903.9".  Your question really is "what is the colour identity of an EDH commander who is colourless and costs colourless mana to cast?" ... applying the answer to that question to the referred to question then gives you the whole picture.

Comment: @cdeszaq - the questions specifies "any EDH deck" which I realize can be confusing since in the context of the game, "any color" does not include colorless, but the question you linked to contains my exact answer.

Comment: @cdeszaq Or perhaps your question really is "Are lands colourless?"

Comment: @Stephen - My goal is to build a colorless EDH deck. The challenge is that all cards within the deck must have a colorless color identity. When searching for lands that generate colorless mana and have a colorless color identity, I ran into a number of cards with the above text. So, the question I am trying to find an answer for is _will those cards work for me in a colorless EDH deck?_. My first attempt to answer the question was not precise enough, and the other question did not address colorless EDH decks and I felt did not give me enough information to answer my specific question.

Comment: @Stephen - Just to clarify, I'm not being snarky here, just trying to get a solid answer to a question that has been bouncing around my play group (and my head) for some time now :) As with everything in MTG, it's sometimes harder to formulate the question correctly, since there are so many moving parts!

Comment: @cdeszaq -  Like I said, its understandable to ask this question separately since "any" means different things depending on how its used.  Stephen and I are just letting you know that this question is answered by the question you linked to.  Its not a "this question should never have been asked" type of thing.  Its a "This question is a subset of an existing question" type of thing.  I recommend modifying the original question to specify that it applies to colorless EDH decks as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we could tidy up all of these questions into one clearly stated one that canonically resolves the issue at hand.  It's starting to get a bit confusing for me now, working out what's going on...

Comment: @thesunneversets - I agree. But, what is the best way to do so? Edit one of them to cover all the bases (there seems to be 2 aspects, and then a combination of the two). Or make a community wiki (cw) question that answers it in one fell swoop and links to the other 3 questions for reference? Or a cw question intended for linking out to "color/colour of mana" questions in general? (might make some sense, since mana color questions tend to all me closely related)

Comment: The 2nd question linked is perfectly fine by itself and is not limited to EDH.  This question and the first one linked are 2 different aspects of the same question.

Comment: Added an answer to the 1st link to explicitly cover the colourless case.

Comment: The rules have changed since you asked this question. Would you mind changing the accepted answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of January 18th, 2016, the restriction on other colors of mana (mentioned in other answer) was [removed](http://mtgcommander.net/EDH_Root/changelog.php).

> Rule 4 removed. Decks may now generate mana of any colour.

They can still be in you deck, but now they can make any color of mana.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  This is mentioned in the first question you linked to.

> 903.9. If mana would be added to a player’s mana pool of a color that isn’t in the color identity of that player’s commander, that amount of colorless mana is added to that player’s mana pool instead.

Comment: @xornob Please do not make edits that substantially change the content of an answer. If an answer is incorrect and the correct answer is very different, downvote it and/or make a comment. If you have a better answer, post it as your own answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I don't know how I feel about the accepted answer being wrong, so I [posted on meta](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1517/6692) to see if we could make an exception for cases like these.